# Error de formato al convertir numero decimal con TO_CHAR dentro de un Stored Procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedure

Se me está presentando una situación extremadamente rara en forma ocasional, cuando se ejecuta un SP en una de cuyas partes existe una conversión de un dato NUMBER(15, 2) a cadena de texto.
El valor numérico debe ser informado a otro sistema diferente, pasandolo como cadena de longitud fija. El otro sistema espera recibir esa cadena y parsea por su lado el dato para usarlo. Para eso convertimos el valor por ejemplo así:

12345.56 => "00000123456"

Para lograrlo hacemos esto:

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(TO_CHAR(valornumerico, "000000000D00"), ".", ""), " ", "")
```

O sea, hacemos que se convierta en una cadena, y le eliminamos el punto decimal obtenido, y preventivamente, quitamos espacios en blanco que pueda haber (es un codigo bastante viejo).
Todo esto anduvo siempre bien... **pero de cuando en cuando** en lugar de obtener

```
00000123456
```

obtenemos algo como

```
000001234,56
```

Es como si en una ejecución del SP inesperadamente el hilo de ejecución del mismo ocurriera con una configuración de idioma diferente, en Español, en lugar de Inglés.

¿Qué puede estar causando este cambio, siendo que NO es permanente, sino sólo en algunas ejecuciones?

Comment: No será un separador de miles no?

Comment: Con el ejemplo que pones, _12345.56 => "00000123456"_, no me queda claro si debes eliminar el cinco que está antes o el que está después del punto decimal, cosa que obviamente tu código no toma en cuenta y es parte del fallo. Sería mejor que pongas un ejemplo con números distintos antes y después del punto decimal.

Comment: Con respecto a lo que comentas del separador de miles, el SP se va a ejecutar en el contexto del `NLS_LANGUAGE` de la conexión que lo invoque, si eventualmente tiene una configuración distinta a la que esperas, es porque ese parámetro de la sesión es distinto al que habitualmente usas (equipo cliente diferente, usuario diferente, procesos ejecutados antes que han cambiado el entorno de la conexión, etc.). Lo mejor sería escribir código que no dependa de eso, por ejemplo, multiplica el número por cien y luego convierte un entero.

Comment: El ejemplo tenía un error, pero la idea es que el valor NUMBER de la tabla se transmite como una cadena de longitud fija a un sistema AS400 que lueg hace su trabajo con el. Nos piden pasar 11 caracteres numéricos, rellenando con ceros a la izquierda, y quitando el separador decimal. Justamente estamos sospechando que el problema se produce a nivel cliente, y lo que necesito es evitarlo porque genera errores graves en el proceso del otro lado (en el AS400), que como son cosas asincronicas, no hay retorno de fallo para gestionar errores desde el nuestro. Nos enteramos tarde del problema..

Answer (score 2):

Yo probaría atacar el problema de otra forma, básicamente convirtiendo el número en un entero y sobre esto hacer el "padding" con '0'.

```
select LPAD(TO_CHAR(CAST(123456.78 * POWER(10,2) AS INTEGER)), 11, '0')
       from dual;
```

Comment: Es una propuesta interesante. Lo voy a analizar en el contexto del SP productivo y luego te comento. Parece una solucion más limpia que la que estamos usando.

Answer (score 1):

La conversión que estas haciendo es correcta en mi entorno de pruebas, lo único que modifiqué fueron las dobles comillas y las cambié por comillas sencillas para que funcionara correctamente:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(TO_CHAR('12345.56' , '999999999D99'), '.', ''), ' ', '')
FROM   dual;
```

En relación a tu problema me suena a la configuración del SET de caracteres en el cliente y el SET de caracteres con el cual ha sido instalada la Base de Datos. Si ocurre esporádicamente, se puede deber a las distintas configuraciones de los clientes.

Si gustas puedes revisar este enlace:
[Configurar Idioma y decimales en Oracle 10g](http://blogcastillodavid.blogspot.com/2007/06/configurar-idioma-y-decimales-en-oracle.html)

Comment: Básicamente confirma las sospechas que hemos estado teniendo. Lamentablemente como la aplicación que invoca al SP es de uso general para multiples (y realmente MULTIPLES) clientes que se conectan desde diferentes subsistemas,tracear en qué maquinas virtuales se están generando los problemas no es tarea simple... y encima implica hacerlo coordinando la gente de  tres equipos de trabajo diferentes. Un asco.
Pero se lo voy a pasar al grupo de BBDD a ver qué podemos hacer.
Gracias por el link ;)